# error in running ica plot function in fast ica toolbox

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm using fast ica toolbox for matlab. i want to use ica plot function for plotting the signal in the first row of matrix ans. I didn't make any changes in ica plot function in the toolbox ,by it gives error. what do I have to do?
Thank you for your help

the error can be seen in the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck9R2.png)

Comment: Please don’t post images of text, copy-paste the error message and a [mre] into your post. See here for arguments: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Comment: Please avoid providing code blocks, logs and errors through images. Copy and paste them in your question as text, and format them (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) correctly (in order to differentiate them from normal text). Some users might not be able to properly see your images or reproduce a minimal example from these images.